# How to know which file an ActiveX wanted to find?

Tags: activex

I have an ActiveX which seems to look for a file when starting. The problem is that the error doesn't give me any clue about which file it cannot access.

The msgbox is : `The system cannot find the file specified`

How can I know which file it wanted to access? Which tool can I use to know that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from Sysinternals/Microsoft.

Comment: An ActiveX control is just a control that you can use in a program. It does not have an identification. Process monitor lists the processes that are executing in the OS.

Comment: Thanks Nano, i have not been able to identify the file it wanted but at least Process Monitor helped me finding what's happening when i launch the process. I can find ActiveX behaviour in iexplore logs